# integrating iAD into 3d game

Tags: iphone, ios, iad, ads, appstore-approval

I'm developing first person shooter and want to integrate iAD (and maybe AdMob later). The problem is that all the ad systems that I know use simple UIView's for that and are based on tapping them. I want to use real 3d game objects as triggers, i.e. when you shot some special character an ad is invoked. The user would be notified about that (so if you don't want ads, just don't shot those objects).

I know how to do that from the technical point of view. But is it legal to do that from the ad provider point of view (and from the Apple review team POV)?

p.s. Or maybe someone knows ad system that could be integrated into my game like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a popup, bannner or full screen ad by hooking your object to a button press with the [RevMob](https://www.revmob.com/) SDK. Their ads tends to be of the 'download a free game' variety.

I don't see how you can do this with Admob or especially iAd as they require the banner ad to be shown on the screen so that they can serve ads. Triggering them like this may be against their terms of service.

Answer (score 1):

I agree to FiddleMeRagged that you can use RevMob for this purpose. You can show a fullscreen ad whenever the user shoots wrong object.

However you can't use Admob for the same purpose. Since they clearly forbid any such activities in their [usage policy](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2623161). They ask you to put maximum one banner ad per screen
Similarly iAd also doesn't allow this kind of ad display.

Apple doesn't seem to have any problem with this, since our game already passed with this kind of functionality. I'll try to find some documentation regarding this.

Edit: Just found [this link](https://www.revmob.com/revenue_tips) on Revmob site, which recommends displaying multiple fullscreen ads.

Answer (score 0):

the existing answers basically cover this, but to clarify regarding iAd:

iAd is based on presenting an ADBannerView, and having that ADBannerView do the work to fetch and display the ad, and then allowing the user to click through to get the full-screen ad.

Apple's documentation on this topic says that if you obscure or hide ads while they are loaded, the ads that your app gets fed will be affected, and your revenue will thus be affected.  (it also says that the ADBannerView itself must conform to certain characteristics.)

in the end … i don't think you'll be able to trigger the full-screen iAd by something in your game being shot, since you won't be able to affect the ADBannerView doing what it needs to do to process the user-click for the click-through.  (well, ok, you maybe could fake this, but it would probably involve the guts of ADBannerView in a way that apple would reject.)

Answer (score 0):

I relize you should probably use revmob but incase you need it in the future, heres a link on integrating iAd and adMob check this link: [Mixing iAd and AdMob](http://www.apptite.be/blog/ios/mixing-iad-and-admob/)

Answer (score 0):

RevMob has an ad unit called adLink, this can be called inside you code and will open the iTunes with the advertised game. You can use the following code:

```
RevMobAds *revmob = [RevMobAds revmob];
[revmob openAdLinkWithDelegate:self];
```

You can find more documentation on their site:
[RevMob API documentation](http://sdk.revmob.com/ios-api/Classes/RevMobAds.html)